# How to unique referrals so I can prevent users from referring the same person

Tags: tracking, analytics

I want to track unique referrals, something that is not easily cheated.. I'll present a use case to better present my problem:

If I put a link on twitter, and someone clicked the link. I have no way to know that the clicker is unique. Maybe he clicked the link before or maybe he changed his ip by using something like proxy or he's using a wifi that have dynamic ip.

I need a way to find unique users to my system. That is not easily cheated..

Comment: Best-case scenario is IP or using a cookie, but neither are reliable. [welcome to the internet]. On the plus side, all those ones that are "cheated uniques" can make up for large internal networks with only have one external IP.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to 100% guarantee the user is unique.  Checking for a cookie can be used but it is super easy for a user to delete.  Checking IP address is slightly better but as you have already mentioned, it is also fairly easy to get around.

Requiring a user to register before it counts is currently the best way to ensure unique visitors.  How solid it is depends on what you require of the user in order to register. Requiring user to validate registration through a code sent in an email greatly helps.  Requiring personal information like credit card, ss#, etc.. helps even more, though it depends on your site as to whether you can realistically expect that sort of information from them.

Other than that...sorry, there is no other way.  As Brad said, "welcome to the internet" :)